# How to get a full path of the running cookbook in the RightScale chef recipe?

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, rightscale

From inside my currently executing cookbook recipe I'd like to get access to it's "current" location on my executing machine.

I need this to get access to it's cached directory structure.

I have a feeling it's located somewhere inside "node[]" but I can't find any documentation about its structure at all.

Any advise?

Thanks

Answer (score 8):

Just found the solution by inspecting the "run_context" instance:

```
ruby_block "reload_client_config" do
  block do
    puts "HERE!!!!!  -> " + run_context.cookbook_collection[cookbook_name].root_dir
  end
  action :create
end
```

This came to me after seeing this thread - [Get deployed cookbook version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13689811/get-deployed-cookbook-version)