# Chef - Get cookbook_path within recipe

Tags: chef-infra

Is there a way to get the `cookbook_path` (defined in either `solo.rb` or `client.rb`) from within a recipe?

I've found this bit:

```
run_context.cookbook_collection
```

Which outputs the cache path of cookbooks, but not the original `cookbook_path`

Comment: What is the `cookbook_path` in your point of view? Documentation says *The sub-directory for cookbooks on the chef-client* . Do you have an example what you expect and what you get? Or are you looking for this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14075847/how-to-get-a-full-path-of-the-running-cookbook-in-the-rightscale-chef-recipe

Comment: So, in `solo.rb` I have defined it as `/path/to/my/cookbooks`. When using `run_context.cookbook_collection` or `::Chef::Config. cookbook_path` it outputs `/etc/chef/local-mode-cache/cache/cookboo‌​ks`

Comment: Did you have a look into `/etc/chef/client.rb` on your remote host? `cookbook_path` has every where the same name, but I think it has different meanings depending on the location (solo.rb vs. knife.rb  vs. client.rb). What is your final goal? What do you try to achive?

Comment: Something weird ... That depends on knowing the original `cookbook_path` ...

Answer (score 0):

You can access the Chef Client's / Solo's configuration settings through [`Chef::Config`](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/chef-config/12.4.1/ChefConfig/Config). In your case, use:

```rb
Chef::Config[:cookbook_path]
```

Comment: This only outputs the cache dir: `/etc/chef/local-mode-cache/cache/cookbooks`